# Flutter : Google Calendar API - Access blocked: project-Client_ID request is invalid

Tags: flutter, authorization, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-apis-explorer

We are facing an issue at the time of redirection to create Google calendar event URL Error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJYMu.png)

Access blocked: project-Client_Id request is invalid, You can’t sign in because project-Client_Id sent an invalid request. You can try again later, or contact the developer about this issue.

We had created the object of the Event. Then added the event to Google Calendar.

Library Used :
googleapis: ^11.3.0
googleapis_auth: ^1.4.1
url_launcher: ^6.1.12

```
class CalendarClient {
  static const _scopes = [CalendarApi.calendarScope];

 insert(title, startTime, endTime) {
 var _clientID = new ClientId(
    "Client_ID",
    "");
  clientViaUserConsent(_clientID, _scopes, prompt).then((AuthClient 
  client) {
  var calendar = CalendarApi(client);
  calendar.calendarList.list().then((value) => 
  print("VAL________$value"));

  String calendarId = "primary";
  Event event = Event(); // Create object of event

  event.summary = title;

  EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime();
  start.dateTime = startTime;
  start.timeZone = "GMT+05:00";
  event.start = start;

  EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime();
  end.timeZone = "GMT+05:00";
  end.dateTime = endTime;
  event.end = end;
  try {
    calendar.events.insert(event, calendarId).then((value) {
      print("ADDEDDD_________________${value.status}");
      if (value.status == "confirmed") {
        log('Event added in google calendar');
      } else {
        log("Unable to add event in google calendar");
      }
    });
  } catch (e) {
    log('Error creating event $e');
  }
});
}
void prompt(String url) async {
print("Please go to the following URL and grant access:");
print("  => $url,, Start Time  >> ");
print("");

if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(url))) {
  await launchUrl(Uri.parse(url));
} else {
  throw 'Could not launch $url';
}
}
}
```

Comment: please include your code

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo Code added please review

Comment: are you using flutter for an installed app or a mobile app https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-use-google-calendar-api-adding-the-events-to-calendar-3d8fcb008493

Comment: Yes follow the same article and still getting the same issue @LindaLawton-DaImTo